# Does the grammar work on this: Nova eruditione requirens dialecticus

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, grammar-choice

Nova eruditione requirens dialecticus (it spells nerd, which is the point of this)

I wanted it to mean "the dialecticus that is searching for new knowledge" but it's been a while since I touched Latin.

Comment: *requiens* is probably a typo. I assume that should be *requirens*.

Comment: Yup it is. Is the rest ok tho?

Answer (score 2):

That is not quite correct: *nova eruditio*, because it is the direct object of *requirere*, should be in the accusative case: *novam eruditionem*.